# Define table of choosed user row in multiple table list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have control dashboard where multiple tables are listed with query

And in dashboard I can switch it to one table from ALLData to User1Table... and vice versa.
When there is only one table chosed I can easily manipulate data. However, I am struggling with updating rows when ALLData(all tables) are listed in dashboard. I can update it checking each table. I was wondering is there any better way to update it.
Tables have no DR. All tables have same column names.

```
 //ALLData
 SELECT * FROM users1
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT * FROM users2...
```

```
user1 
id name tel status
1  Bob  911   1

user2 
id name tel status
3  Anna 11   0
3  Jack 12   1

//ALLData in dashboard
id name tel status
1  Bob  911   1
3  Anna 11    0
3  Jack 12    1
```

I can use id and status as PK

Comment: If name and tel of both tables are same then is there any logic. If you wanna to use id and status as PK then create a composite primary key with this two columns.

Comment: @id'7238 Bob cannot appear in user2. He is in user1. In dashboard I am showing all data from those tables using SELECT * FROM users1 UNION ALL  SELECT * FROM users2. When I change status of Bob in dashboard to change it in DB and need to update Bob status by checking each table cause I dont know in dashboard to which table Bob belongs. This is example, in real I have more than 10 tables and thousands of data

Comment: @RahulBiswas yes there is. Each table belongs to specific site. User1 table belongs to site1 and user2->site2